# Is the following function convex or not?

Tags: convex-analysis

$$f(x,y)=-x\log(1+y)$$
The Hessian matrix of $f(x,y)$ is
$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 & -\frac{1}{1+y}\\
-\frac{1}{1+y} & \frac{x}{(1+y)^2}
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Then the eigen value is $-\frac{1}{(1+y)^2}$.

Since it is not positive, $f(x,y)$ is not convex. Right??

However, papers said it is convex.

Please let me know why it is convex.

Comment: It is not convex. Are you sure you didn't misunderstand what the papers say? What are the papers you talk about?

Comment: Hmm... ah not convex?? I am correct?? thank you for giving me confidence. I will check again the paper. So hard to understand it sorry for bad question....